# What is the best procedure to update thousands of rows in the tables having key constraints

Tags: mysql

I know that any RDBMS wont allow to update the table due to foreign key constraints. So i had copied the table `{newtablename}` using:

```
 create table table_name select * from table_org;
```

By following this process, key fields will not be copied, after carrying out data modifications in copied table rows, deleting the master table, renaming the copied table to original table and updating the table definition to add the key fields ( relations) by executing script which was copied using :

```
 show create table table_name;
```

By executing the script adding the Primay key, keys, constraints and rebuilding the relations. Is this a better procedure to to update rows for the tables having index and key constraints, or please suggest a simple procedure to update rows.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Can you edit your question for readability? It's hard to understand what you are asking.  Also, look at the markdown so you can format your sql queries as code samples.

Comment: Constraints are in place for a reason. If you are creating another table to modify data that doesn't conform to the specified integrity, just to use this table later on by renaming it and to now wanting to apply back the original constraints, there's a problem with your implementation.

Comment: @Ryan: True but not all DB engines support deferrable constraints. It may be that he's juggling with such a use-case.